# Is Intel's Last Branch Record feature unique to Intel processors?

Tags: x86, arm, intel, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers

Last Branch Record refers to a collection of register pairs (MSRs) that store the source and destination addresses related to recently executed branches. They are supported across Intel Core 2, Intel Xeon and Intel Atom processor families. http://css.csail.mit.edu/6.858/2012/readings/ia32/ia32-3b.pdf document has more information in case you are interested.

Is LBR-like feature available only in Intel microprocessors OR something similar exists in ARM etc. ?

Comment: LBR in this case is a profiling / debugging mechanism right? It is not some aspect of internal / regular branch prediction?

Comment: Yes, I don't think it is a part of branch prediction mechanism. It is simply a queue of branches that were taken recently.

Comment: ARM has trace functionality on some processors, too.  http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.set.coresight/index.html

Comment: @auselen When your code takes a `jmp` to a nonsense address and/or takes a `call` and messed up the stack by the time it crashed, you normally can't tell what caused it. The last branch feature lets you find it instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum up, as Carl mentioned, ARM also has program tracing functionality on some processors. This site has interesting details about this feature : http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.set.coresight/index.html

Comment: Does it trace last branches?

Comment: @WindChaser, ARM Coresight has some "Program Flow Tracing", check http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ihi0035b/BCGHCADA.html