# what's the equivalent of Last Branch Record (LBR) on ARM and POWERPC?

Tags: profiling, perf

I'm collecting some profiling information on intel using perf record  about taken branches and I'm using -b to make use of LBR. Is there any similar support on ARM and PowerPC? And yes I've seen this:
[Is Intel's Last Branch Record feature unique to Intel processors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595931/is-intels-last-branch-record-feature-unique-to-intel-processors)

Comment: File http://web.eece.maine.edu/~vweaver/projects/perf_events/sampling/pebs_ibs_sampling.pdf from 2016 lists no equivalent for ARM in 2.4 section and no data known to author for POWER in 2.5 section: "2.4    ARM ARM has no PEBS or IBS equivalent,  but it does have something similar to processor trace called CoreSight". POWER9 PMU has BHRB (Branch history rolling buffer) https://wiki.raptorcs.com/w/images/6/6b/POWER9_PMU_UG_v12_28NOV2018_pub.pdf but I not sure is it the same as LBR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ARM CPUs this option has been available since ARMv9.2-A - it's called Branch Record Buffer Extension (BRBE). More information about the topic: https://lwn.net/Articles/951316/ .

Regarding PowerPC. Just got an update from PowerPC maintainers in the Linux kernel. For PowerPC, such a feature is called Branch History Rolling Buffer (BHRB). It's available since Power8 (~2013).